# bionic (18.04LTS): PHP 7.3, Package availability

Tags: apt, php7

I am aware of the existing Ubuntu Packages site (https://packages.ubuntu.com/en/bionic/). But how to know which Php version will be supported ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://packages.ubuntu.com/

There is search engine. If you use it, you'll find out that php 7.2 is currently in `bionic` repositories.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=php&searchon=names

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/php7.2

php 7.3 will be provided officially in Ubuntu 19.10 eoan.

Comment: Thank you Pilot6. How did you get the information that php 7.3 will be provided officially in Ubuntu 19.10 eoan ? Does it mean that there will be no php 7.3 apt support?

Comment: If you click my search link, you'll see that eoan has 7.3. What is "7.3 apt support"? I don't know if php 7.3 will be provided for `bionic` or not. Most likely it won't.

Comment: I mean available through an 'apt upgrade'. However it's all crystal clear. Thank you for your time.

Comment: 7.2 will get security upgrades, but won't upgrade to 7.3.